# Is it possible to play sound when a device is locked?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm making an alarm app for my android device with phonegap and I'm wondering if it's possible to play a sound when the device is locked and the timer runs out

Answer (score 0):

Yes. On Android, do this to schedule a wakeup per the real-time clock:

```
private static final long WINDOW_MS = 50L; // Allow some time flexibility to save battery power.

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = makeAlarmPendingIntent(context);
long nextReminder = ... // the SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() for the next reminder notification
alarmMgr.setWindow(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, nextReminder - WINDOW_MS,
                   WINDOW_MS, pendingIntent);
```

With a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive this `pendingIntent`. When the relevant `Intent` arrives, use a `Notification` to play a sound. See `NotificationCompat.Builder` and its `setSound()` method.

Cordova might provide the needed APIs to do this. If not, you'll have to implement it in the Java portion of your app.